# Perl - Reading .txt files line-by-line and using compare function (printing non-matches only once)

Tags: perl, unique, element

I am really struggling and have spent about two full days on this banging my head against receiving the same result every time I run this perl script.

I have a Perl script that connects to a vendor tool and stores data for ~26 different elements within **@data**.  There is a foreach loop for @data that breaks the 26 elements into $e->{'element1'), $e->{'element2'), $e->{'element3'), $e->{'element4'), etc. etc. etc.

I am also reading from the .txt files within a directory (line-by-line) and comparing the server names that exist within the text files with what exists in **$e->{'element4'}**.

**The Problem:**

Matches are working perfectly and only printing **one line** for each of the 26 elements when there is a match, however non-matches are producing one line for every entry within the .txt files (37 in all).  So if there are 100 entries (each entry having 26 elements) stored within @data, then there are 100 x 37 entries being printed.

So for every non-match in the:  if ($e->{'element4'} eq '6' && $_ =~ /$e->{element7}/i) statement below, I am receiving a print out saying that there is not a match.   37 entries for the same identical 26 elements (because there are 37 total entries in all of the .txt files).

**The Goal:**

I need to print out only 1 line for each unique entry (a unique entry being $e->{element1} thru $e->{element26}).  It is already printing one 1 line for matches, but it is printing out 37 entries when there is not a match.   I need to treat matches and non-matches differently.

**Code:**

```
foreach my $e (@data) {
    # Open the .txt files stored within $basePath and use for comparison:
    opendir( DIRC, $basePath . "/" ) || die("cannot open directory");
    my @files = ( readdir(DIRC) );
    my @MPG_assets = grep( /(.*?).txt/, @files );

    # Loop through each system name found and compare it with the data in SC for a match:
    foreach (@MPG_assets) {
        $filename = $_;
        open( MPGFILES, $basePath . "/" . $filename ) || die "canot open the file";
        while (<MPGFILES>) {
            if ( $e->{'element4'} eq '6' && $_ =~ /$e->{'element7'}/i ) {
                ## THIS SECTION WORKS PERFECTLY AND ONLY PRINTS MATCHES WHERE $_
                ## (which contains the servernames (1 per line) in the .txt files)
                ## EQUALS $e->{'element7'}.
                print $e->{'element1'} . "\n";
                print $e->{'element2'} . "\n";
                print $e->{'element3'} . "\n";
                print $e->{'element4'} . "\n";
                print $e->{'element5'} . "\n";
                # ...
                print $e->{'element26'} . "\n";

            } else {
                ## **THIS SECTION DOES NOT WORK**.  FOR EVERY NON-MATCH, THERE IS A
                ## LINE PRINTED WITH 26 IDENTICAL ELEMENTS BECAUSE ITS LOOPING THRU
                ## THE 37 LINES IN THE *.TXT FILES.

                print $e->{'element1'} . "\n";
                print $e->{'element2'} . "\n";
                print $e->{'element3'} . "\n";
                print $e->{'element4'} . "\n";
                print $e->{'element5'} . "\n";
                # ...
                print $e->{'element26'} . "\n";
            }    # End of 'if ($e->{'element4'} eq..' statement
        }    # End of while loop
    }    # End of 'foreach(@MPG_assets)'
}    # End of 'foreach my $e (@data)'
```

I think I need something to identical unique elements and define what fields make up a unique element but honestly I have tried everything I know.   If you would be so kind to provide actual code fixes, that would be wonderful because I am headed to production with this script quite soon.  Also. I am looking for code (ideally) that is very human-readable because I will need to document it so others can understand.

Please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: `open( my $mpgfiles, '<', $basePath . '/' . $filename ) or die "Cannot open $filename: $!";` Indirect filehandles are lexical and automatically close when they go out of scope. Three-args `open` protects from unexpected pipe opens/command execution. Low precedence `or` instead of `||` prevents the behavior from being changed if the parentheses are removed. The errno variable `$!` should be included in the exception if the `open` fails.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would push all bad nodes to an array and pull what I wanted with List::MoreUtils. Also, a sample of the results might be helpful as well.

```
# 1/2 Sudo Code
# =========================
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

#...

else
{
    while ( $i <= 26 ) {
        push @nonMatches, $e->{'element$i++'};
    }

    my @badElements = uniq @nonMatches;
    foreach $element ( @badElements )
    {
        print $element;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will consider this suggestion as well.  The # of elements listed in my sample are actually named in the real code.  Meaning:  $e->{'ID'}, $e->{'Name'}, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're testing if a particular line matches 'element 7', and if it does - printing all the elements. And it it *doesn't* match, you appear to be doing the same thing?

What are you trying to do in that `else` codeblock?

I will hazard a guess that what you might want to try is:

```
my %match_found_in;
my %match_found_of;
while(my $line = <MPGFILES>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ($e->{'element4'} eq '6' && $line =~ /$e->{'element7'}/i) { 
        $match_found_in{$filename} = $line; 
        $match_found_of{$e->{'element7'}} = $filename;
    }
}

foreach my $element ( keys %match_found_of ) {
  print "$element had a match in ".$match_found_of{$element},"\n";
}

foreach my $filename ( keys %match_found_in ) {
  print "$filename had a match on :", $match_found_in{$filename},"\n";   
}
```

Or am I missing what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Matches are being sent through a tool to our automation software for further processing.  Matches should include a new element called something like $e->{'groupType'} which contains the FILENAME where the match was found in (which .txt file).  NON-MATCHES should also be sent using the same identical elements except the $e->{'groupType'} element should be statically set to 'Standard'.    I am using print statements just to sample what data is captured.  I will try your suggestion now.  The end goal is to have just 1 line printed for every one of the 100 entries stored within @data.

Comment: this is much better than my prior result.  I am receiving two entries for every non-match (and of course the expect one entry for matches).   Do I need to add something to the end of the else loop to mark the finding as seen before?  This is already a big help, thanks!!

Comment: So, in digging a little deeper, it is showing 2 results for non-matches because there are 2 total text files in the directory where it is looking.   I am okay with two, but would prefer a single entry for each of the 100 entries within @data. Thanks in advance regardless!

Comment: Use a hash, and extract a key (server name?). `$_` when iterating `MPGFILES` for example. E.g. `$match_found{$_} = $filename`. Then you can do a `foreach my $key ( keys %match_found )`. (Or similar, capturing server name.). As a point of note though - you're `$_ =~ m/$e->{'element7'}/` may match more than you expect, as it'll match a substring (you may want to prefix with \A and suffix with \Z). Also - because you're doing a `while` on a filehandle, you'll be getting linefeeds.

Comment: updated answer to illustrate - did two different things, because I'm still not entirely sure what results you're after - note, this'll skip dupes, because if two files have the same match, the second will replace the first.

Comment: So the current solution appears to be stopping after the first match is found.   It's true there should only be one match for each entry in /@/data, but /@/data consists of 26 elements.  Here's the deal, $e->{'element7'} may be the same for multiple entries.  A unique entry is when:  $e->{'element1'}, $e->{'element2'}, $e->{'element4'}, and $e->{'element7'} are all the same.  $e->{'element7'} may be seen multiple times with different elements1, 2, and 4.   Sorry that I didn't fully explain this properly from the beginning.  Do I need to tell the hash what constitutes a unique entry?  Thanks!!

Comment: Still looking for a solution here.

Comment: Hashes keys are intrinsically unique. That's the point of using a hash. That uniqueness allows you to test if e.g. an element has been seen already (is in the hash) or not, and it'll coalesce duplicates, because if you update the hash, you'll only update the value associated with that key.